# How to show and delete all variables

Tags: graphics

1. How can I show all currently active variables in MM?  I've lost track of which variables I've defined and old variables are corrupting new variables (even variables defined in different notebooks).
2. How can I delete all currently active variables in MM?  Do I have to delete them one by one?

(BTW - I'm new here.)
Thank you.

Comment: I tend to just call `Exit[]` and restart the kernel when I want a clean slate.  You can also call ```ClearAll["Global`*"]``` to just clear variables you've defined.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Answer (score 4):

I assume in question #1 you're concerned with variables that you have defined yourself. You were probably defining them in the Global context, so you can see all such variables with this:

```
Names["Global`*"]
```

You could try `Names[]` if you're curious about all of the symbols currently "active" across all contexts (so, this includes all of the System symbols as well).

For #2, you can "delete" to a variety of degrees. The most common is probably `ClearAll`:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

I suggest that you look up `Names` and `ClearAll` in the documentation and follow the threads. You might find several other useful tools.

**UPDATE**

This is found in the documentation, but just for completeness here...

ClearAll doesn't actually remove the variable from Mathematica's "memory". It simply removes all definitions (OwnValues, DownValues, etc) and attributes associated with the symbol(s). For most use cases, this is sufficient and preferable. To make Mathematica actually "forget" the symbol(s), use Remove.

So, in your question, you said "old variables are corrupting new variables". ClearAll should fix that problem (unless I'm misunderstanding you). But you could go "nuclear" and use Remove. Alternatively the ultimate "nuclear" is to kill and restart the kernel.

Comment: Thanks – but it’s not working the way I expect it to.  I created a variable Testvar = x+7, then entered ClearAll["Global`*"] and I still see Testvar defined when I enter Names["Global`*"]

Comment: Right. I should have been clearer. I'll update the answer.

Comment: While `Testvar` is still in the Global context, whatever definitions you created for it will be cleared.

Comment: OK – but is it just me or wouldn’t you think there was a much simpler, more elegant way to clear all variables than to restart the kernel?  I’m not missing something obvious am I?

Comment: Clear, ClearAll, Remove. How are these functions difficult? What kind of thing did you have in mind?